# Compile two queries to one set of results?

Tags: wp-query

I've got a big query that queries one `post_type` with all different kinds of filters. Values are taken from `<form>` inputs.

- Im adding 3 different checkboxes to the `<form>` which can
  be used as `post_type` toggle - this means that you can query only one `post_type` of the three, two of them or all at once
- Every `post_type` has it's own inputs that I show / hide with jQuery
- `post_type` inputs should only *affect / filter* its own `post_type`
- All the results must be displayed in same list

---

My question is: how to query different `post_types` when each have its own arguments?

---

**Thoughts after few days of thinking about this:**

- Three different queries (*poor, poor performance*) and compile multiple queries into one loop?

  - While Im having tons of query arguments, it should drastically speed up query because there's pretty narrow scope, at least my logic says it and three different queries shouldn't be that bad even if each have thousands of posts?
  - My only concern is that user can also query without filling any inputs which means that all three queries are quering ALL the posts.
- Including several `post_types` seems impossible - you cannot use different `metas` and `taxes` on different `post_types` using conditional logic in same query, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combining two wordpress queries with pagination is not working](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/159228/combining-two-wordpress-queries-with-pagination-is-not-working)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/112612/21376

Comment: I have never tried but I should think it would be possible. Could you post the query code you have up to now.

Comment: Im afraid this is not reasonable because even if not combined, each query is at least 700 liner. I will try plugin mentioned in previous comments. Im not sure though if there's a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be nice if you query all three `post_type`s at the same time, using one query, and then manipulating it using `php`.

Consider this query:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array( 'pt1', 'pt2', 'pt3' ),
    'meta_key' => BUMP!!!!
);
```

You can not use an array of `meta_key`s.

So, I think the only way is to use `wp_db` object and make your own custom query:

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results( 
    "
    SELECT ID, post_title 
    FROM $wpdb->posts
    WHERE post_type = 'pt1' OR post_type = 'pt2' OR post_type = 'pt3' 
        AND ...
    "
);

foreach( $results as $result ){
    echo $result->post_title;
    // ...
}
```

and then use `php` to separate and show the results.